# Character encoding issues for Russian Chars

Tags: character-encoding

@ http://tinyurl.com/7v67lnh I am working on a new page for a client. The character encoding I am using is utf 8:`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>` Also added a unicode BOM signature
. But somehow the Russian code in the right sidebar is mangled. Any ideas why?

Comment: Currently I can see the Russian words displayed correctly in both Chrome and IE.

Comment: All OK in Chrome 16.0.912.59 beta and Safari 5.1.1 on my OSX 10.6.8, true. Just not on FF 8.0.1. Did empty cache, but that did not help.

Comment: When I set character encoding utf-8 in FF 8.0.1 I do see all corectly, but shouldn't Firefox just pick up the encoding I asked for?

Comment: Solved it all by adding `AddDefaultCharset UTF-8` to the .htaccess. Apparently the server was going for another character encoding such as Cyrillic or Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment to my question:

> Solved it all by adding AddDefaultCharset UTF-8 to the .htaccess.
>   Apparently the server was going for another character encoding such as
>   Cyrillic or Windows. –

Answer (score 4):

use UTF-8 for your html page too, add this tag to your html code `<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">` upon your `title tag`

Comment: Tried `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">` , but no success. Still need to turn Unicode 8 on in FireFox 8.0.1

Comment: See comment above. A default character encoding had to be added to the .htaccess. That seems to do the trick. Also all good in IE8

Comment: i think this problem in your browser,i can see it correctly in fox 3.6.3

Comment: Could be a FF 8.0.1 issue, true. Have not had a confirmation on this yet. Might file a bug report just to see if it is. Could always be an extension issue as well. Would be the first FF character encoding issue though. And now I have the issue using the same page on the Russian version. I cannot add utf8 to the .htaccess as that screws up the Russian menu and text on other pages.